# Change Cognito UserPool email to mutable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is there a way to enable the email field for editing without having to create a new UserPool?

[See the blocked field here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubciY.png)

The email attribute is marked as readable + writable.

I also tried changing the user's email using adminUpdateUserAttributes but that didn't work either.

When I tried to use the adminUpdateUserAttributes I got the following error message:

> InvalidParameterException: user.email: Attribute cannot be updated.

Comment: No, that's why Cognito sucks. You have to create a new pool and migrate everything over.